# Need simple audio amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, audio

I'm working on an arduino project and it's not loud enough. I was trying to drive a piezo buzzer to make a noise sufficient enough to distract a friend's new kittens when they are fighting. Fidelity is not a huge concern and I can either drive a bigger piezo buzzer (passive 3-24v) or an 8ohm speaker. I have one of each.

I'm trying to create a noise maker so sound quality is not as big of an issue. I've been searching over the internet and found a few circuits I am going to try, but most are built for fidelity and I do not have all the parts needed in any case.

I have a mix-and-mosh of ceramic, mylar polarized/unpolarized caps, a whole variety of resistors covering most common values, and a mixed bag of potentiometers. The transistors I have available include 2n2222/2n2222As, 2n3904, 2n3906, BC347, and it appears I even have some BS250 FETs. I also have some LM386Ls (the circuit I'm working on now uses those, but I'm having to parallel some polarized caps to hit 220uF for one side as I don't seem to have any of those on hand).

I'm aware there are some transistor based circuits, but I'm not sure what I can build with what I have and searching over the internet looking for something suitable is exhausting when you aren't entirely sure what the hell you are looking at in the first place. My electronics skills are pretty much like my old college russian skills - I can still read a schematic just fine and figure out what pin to plug to what, but don't know how to put the pieces together and get the desired result. So you can assume I can read a schematic, but have long since forgotten what little I knew of ohm's law and the rest and would prefer not to spend 3 weeks catching up so I can build a simple amp to scare some cats!

Answer (score 1):

You can drive the piezo from a PWM output on the Arduino; you should be able to get it to output on an annoying frequency.

Comment: I was using toneAC2 - part of my problem is that the person wants these hooked up wirelessly and most of the transceivers I can get on the cheap use pins 9 and 10 which are the ones that tend to put out more umph for audio.

Comment: that and the pro minis I picked up were pre-soldered to 3.3v. I'd prefer to keep them there for power conservation when not in use. Plus if I build an amp, I'm not restricted to just synthesized sine or pulse waves but can use either a more advance synth library or even play audio files.

Comment: Which part wirelessly? you mean wireless between the arduino and the noisemaker?

Comment: And you might be better using ToneAC instead? it effectively doubles the output so it might be loud enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a circuit (in French) with LM386](http://www.sonelec-musique.com/electronique_realisations_ampli_bf_003.html).

[Here's another one using transistors.](http://www.sonelec-musique.com/electronique_bases_amplis_bf_mini.html)

There are other different circuits on [that website (http://www.sonelec-musique.com/)](http://www.sonelec-musique.com/).